# Codecademy function/switch

Tags: javascript

I'm working through Codecademy. I need to create a function that takes a movie name and gives a movie review based on the movie entered. I need to do this using a `switch` statement.

It asks the user to create a function called `getReview`, and he must use a `switch` to provide the possible output. I'm not sure about the syntax/relationship between the function and the `switch`. Here is what I wrote:

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    switch (movie) {
          case "Toy Story 2":
          "Great story. Mean prospector."
           break;
          case "Finding Nemo":
             "Cool animation, and funny turtles"
             break;
         case "The Lion King":
            "Great songs."
             break;
         default:
             "I don't know!"
             break;
     }
  };
```

I get an error from Codecademy asking "Are you sure you're returning the right thing?

Comment: Well, you don't return anything. To return you need to use `return`.

Comment: Your function doesn't have any `return` statements, so it's not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a return statement to each `case`.

Normally, you want to add a `break` statement to each `case` in your switch. However, since you're `return`ing, there's no possibility of your switch "falling through." If you're unsure of what that means, look at this example:

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
        console.log("hi #1")
    case 2:
        console.log("hi #2")
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log("hi #3")
        break;
}
```

If `x == 1`, then

```
hi #1
hi #2
```

would appear in the console. Compare this to if `x == 2` or `x == 3`. Then only `"hi #2"` or `"hi #3"`, respectively, would appear in the console.

This is because, after completing `case 1`, the computer moves on: you need `break` to stop it. However, by `return`ing, you essentially call `break`, since the function returns and therefore won't continue falling through the `case`s.

Either way, this is how I'd set it up:

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    switch (movie) {
        case "Toy Story 2": return "Great story. Mean prospector."
        // all your other cases
        default: return "movie not in library"
    }
 }
```

Alternatively (the syntax is not as clean), you can return a variable at the end:

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    var line = ""
    switch (movie) {
        case "Toy Story 2":
            line =  "Great story. Mean prospector."
            break;
        // all your other cases
        default:
            line = "movie not in library"
            break;    // this `break` is optional
    }
    return line
 }
```

Comment: I like the return variable instead of 10 different returns.

Comment: @Hanoncs I do too. I just figured this was a good teaching opportunity for the OP, so I wanted to include the other possibilities.

Comment: plus 1, too bad stack users are all mean now, things like this deserve to be voted up.

Comment: Thank you royhowie! This was a very instructive response. I like the elegance of the single return statement. This was my first question ever on this website.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting a string in a statement doesn't do anything with it. The function is supposed to return the message, so you have to use `return` statements.

```js
var getReview = function(movie) {
  switch (movie) {
    case "Toy Story 2":
      return "Great story. Mean prospector."
      break;
    case "Finding Nemo":
      return "Cool animation, and funny turtles"
      break;
    case "The Lion King":
      return "Great songs."
      break;
    default:
      return "I don't know!"
      break;
  }
};

alert(getReview(prompt("What movie?")));
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm very new to coding, as you can tell. Bonehead mistake I guess.